# Dividir una lista en dos columnas sin afectar otras listas dentro de ella

Tags: css

Hola tengo problemas para dividir una lista en dos columnas sin afectar otras que están dentro de ellas, la lista es algo asi:

```
<ul id="rtl_func">

<li class="list_root" id="f_0">Tipos de Datos
    <ul id="c_0">
        <li class="list_child">Enteros, Ordinales</li>
        <li class="list_child">Puntos Flotantes</li>
        <li class="list_child">Cadenas, Char</li>
        <li class="list_child">Punteros</li>
        <li class="list_child">Otros</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="list_root" id="f_1">Cadenas y Char
    <ul id="c_1">
        <li class="list_child">Operaciones</li>
        <li class="list_child">Convertir desde</li>
        <li class="list_child">Convertir hacia</li>
        <li class="list_child">Presentación</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="list_root" id="f_2">Estructura del Programa
    <ul id="c_2">
        <li class="list_child">Control del Programa</li>
        <li class="list_child">Datos del Programa</li>
        <li class="list_child">Ciclos</li>
        <li class="list_child">Lógica</li>
        <li class="list_child">Orientado a Objetos</li>
    </ul>
</li>

.....
</ul>
```

y mi hoja de estilo es el siguiente:

```
#rtl_func li {
  list-style:none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#rtl_func ul[id|=f_] li { display:inline}

#rtl_func ul[id|=f_] li:nth-child(4):before {display: block; content: '';}

#rtl_func li.list_root {
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
}
```

pero no logro dividir la lista en dos columnas sin que afecte las listas dentro de ella.

Aqui un ejemplo en [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emksft3a/)

Saludos

**Actualización:**

he actualizado el jsFiddle con las recomendaciones de @learnercys y aún sigue sin dividirse en dos columnas.

Comment: cuál es el estilo que no te funciona ? el `#rtl_func li`?

Comment: Pues el estilo tal como lo tengo debería de dividir la lista en dos columnas, sin que afecte la lista de adentro. cualquier cambio que hago la lista de adentro se vuelve inline o sea que se ponen de lado a lado.

Comment: Acabo de probar la siguiente regla `ul#rtl_func{  
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
} ` me crea las dos columnas pero me deja un feo efecto y es que uno de los elementos se "parte" en dos entre las dos columnas.

Comment: Solo como consejo, solo deberías de utilizar el selector `#` en estilos muy específicos. Entonces tu problema esta en el `display: inline` ? que lo aplica a los `li` más internos y solo necesitas que se haga a los `.list-root`?

Comment: Es correcto, lo que necesito es que los li con la clase .list_root se dividan en dos columnas, vamos a decir si hay 7 li root serían 4 en una columna y 3 en la otra sin que afecte los li internos. es como hace este script Jquery (http://www.madeincima.it/download/samples/jquery/easyListSplitter/) mas abajo veras como divide en columnas con hijos incluyendo., al final me decanto con utilizarlo si no es posible con css.

Comment: La hoja de estilos de la pregunta no tiene mucho sentido (la mitad de los estilos no aplican a nada): no hay ningún `ul` cuyo id comience por "f_", y los estilos de los `li` sólo se aplicarían a los más internos (porque #rtl_func es un ul, entonces sólo serían inline los de las sublistas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que la lista se divida en dos columnas, vas bien encaminado con el método que mencionas en los comentarios (usando `columns`):

```
ul#rtl_func{ 
  columns: 2; 
  -webkit-columns: 2; 
  -moz-columns: 2; 
}
```

Pero eso hace que inicialmente alguna de las listas internas se rompa de manera un poco rara (a mitad de lista). Para evitar eso puedes usar la propiedad `break-inside` con el valor `avoid` que evita que un elemento se rompa entre dos columnas. Sólo tendrías que aplicarselo a las `li` externas:

```
ul#rtl_func > li { 
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid; 
}
```

El resultado quedaría así (con el código del JSFiddle):

```js
var librerias = {
  "data": [
    {
      "main": "Types",        
      "text":"Tipos de Datos",
      "child":[
        {"display": "Enteros, Ordinales", "value": "Ints"},
        {"display": "Puntos Flotantes", "value": "Floats"},
        {"display": "Cadenas, Char", "value": "Strings"},
        {"display": "Punteros", "value": "Pointers"},
        {"display": "Otros", "value": "Otros"}
      ]

    },
    {
      "main": "Strings",        
      "text": "Cadenas y Char",
      "child":[
        {"display": "Operaciones", "value": "Calcs" },
        {"display": "Convertir desde", "value": "ConvsFrom" },
        {"display": "Convertir hacia", "value": "ConvsTo" },
        {"display": "Presentación", "value": "Display" }
      ]

    },
    {
      "main": "PgmStruct",        
      "text": "Estructura del Programa",
      "child":[
        {"display": "Control del Programa", "value": "Control" },
        {"display": "Datos del Programa", "value": "Data" },
        {"display": "Ciclos", "value": "Loops" },
        {"display": "Lógica", "value": "Logic" },
        {"display": "Orientado a Objetos", "value": "Object" }
      ]

    },
    {
      "main": "Numbers",        
      "text": "Números y Conjuntos",
      "child":[
        {"display": "Cálculos", "value": "Calcs" },
        {"display": "Convertir Desde", "value": "ConvsFrom" },
        {"display": "Convertir Hacia", "value": "ConvsTo" },
        {"display": "Trigonometría", "value": "Trig" },
        {"display": "Números por defecto", "value": "Values" },
        {"display": "Presentación", "value": "Display" }
      ]

    },
    {
      "main": "Options",        
      "text": "Opciones",
      "child":[
        {"display": "Opciones de Control", "value": "Control" },
        {"display": "Opciones de Datos", "value": "Data" }
      ]

    },  
    {
      "main": "DatesAndTimes",        
      "text": "Fechas y Tiempos",
      "child":[
        {"display": "Cálculos", "value": "Calcs" },
        {"display": "Convertir Desde", "value": "ConvsFrom" },
        {"display": "Convertir Hacia", "value": "ConvsTo" },
        {"display": "Valores", "value": "Values" },
        {"display": "Presentación", "value": "Display" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "main": "Files",        
      "text": "Archivos",
      "child":[
        {"display": "Operaciones", "value": "Control" },
        {"display": "Acceso de Datos", "value": "Data" },
        {"display": "Manejo", "value": "Strings" }
      ]

    }, 
  ]      
};

$(librerias.data).each(function(index){
  $('#rtl_func').append('<li id="f_' + index + '" class="list_root">' + this.text + '<ul id="c_'+index+'"></ul>');
  $(this.child).each(function(i){
    $('#c_' + index).append('<li class="list_child">' + this.display + '</li>');
  });
  $('#rtl_func').append('</li>');
});
```

```css
#rtl_func li {
  list-style:none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#rtl_func ul[id|=f_] li { display:inline}

#rtl_func ul[id|=f_] li:nth-child(4):before {display: block; content: '';}

#rtl_func li.list_root {
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
}

/* Mostrar la lista en dos columnas */
ul#rtl_func { 
  columns: 2; 
  -webkit-columns: 2; 
  -moz-columns: 2; 
}

/* no romper los elementos externos */
ul#rtl_func > li { 
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="rtl_func">
</ul>
```

---

Como [indica Equiso en su comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6484/dividir-una-lista-en-dos-columnas-sin-afectar-otras-listas-dentro-de-ella/6514?noredirect=1#comment11871_6514), el soporte a `break-inside` no está muy extendido (aunque no es tan malo como lo pinta MDN, como se puede ver en [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=break-inside)). Así que aquí dejo una alternativa usando `display` y `width` que sí son soportados por todos los navegadores:

```js
var librerias = {
  "data": [
    {
      "main": "Types",        
      "text":"Tipos de Datos",
      "child":[
        {"display": "Enteros, Ordinales", "value": "Ints"},
        {"display": "Puntos Flotantes", "value": "Floats"},
        {"display": "Cadenas, Char", "value": "Strings"},
        {"display": "Punteros", "value": "Pointers"},
        {"display": "Otros", "value": "Otros"}
      ]

    },
    {
      "main": "Strings",        
      "text": "Cadenas y Char",
      "child":[
        {"display": "Operaciones", "value": "Calcs" },
        {"display": "Convertir desde", "value": "ConvsFrom" },
        {"display": "Convertir hacia", "value": "ConvsTo" },
        {"display": "Presentación", "value": "Display" }
      ]

    },
    {
      "main": "PgmStruct",        
      "text": "Estructura del Programa",
      "child":[
        {"display": "Control del Programa", "value": "Control" },
        {"display": "Datos del Programa", "value": "Data" },
        {"display": "Ciclos", "value": "Loops" },
        {"display": "Lógica", "value": "Logic" },
        {"display": "Orientado a Objetos", "value": "Object" }
      ]

    },
    {
      "main": "Numbers",        
      "text": "Números y Conjuntos",
      "child":[
        {"display": "Cálculos", "value": "Calcs" },
        {"display": "Convertir Desde", "value": "ConvsFrom" },
        {"display": "Convertir Hacia", "value": "ConvsTo" },
        {"display": "Trigonometría", "value": "Trig" },
        {"display": "Números por defecto", "value": "Values" },
        {"display": "Presentación", "value": "Display" }
      ]

    },
    {
      "main": "Options",        
      "text": "Opciones",
      "child":[
        {"display": "Opciones de Control", "value": "Control" },
        {"display": "Opciones de Datos", "value": "Data" }
      ]

    },  
    {
      "main": "DatesAndTimes",        
      "text": "Fechas y Tiempos",
      "child":[
        {"display": "Cálculos", "value": "Calcs" },
        {"display": "Convertir Desde", "value": "ConvsFrom" },
        {"display": "Convertir Hacia", "value": "ConvsTo" },
        {"display": "Valores", "value": "Values" },
        {"display": "Presentación", "value": "Display" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "main": "Files",        
      "text": "Archivos",
      "child":[
        {"display": "Operaciones", "value": "Control" },
        {"display": "Acceso de Datos", "value": "Data" },
        {"display": "Manejo", "value": "Strings" }
      ]

    }, 
  ]      
};

$(librerias.data).each(function(index){
  $('#rtl_func').append('<li id="f_' + index + '" class="list_root">' + this.text + '<ul id="c_'+index+'"></ul>');
  $(this.child).each(function(i){
    $('#c_' + index).append('<li class="list_child">' + this.display + '</li>');
  });
  $('#rtl_func').append('</li>');
});
```

```css
#rtl_func li {
  list-style:none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#rtl_func ul[id|=f_] li { display:inline}

#rtl_func ul[id|=f_] li:nth-child(4):before {display: block; content: '';}

#rtl_func li.list_root {
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
}

/* Mostrar la lista en dos columnas */
ul#rtl_func { 
  columns: 2; 
  -webkit-columns: 2; 
  -moz-columns: 2; 
}

/* no romper los elementos externos */
ul#rtl_func > li { 
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="rtl_func">
</ul>
```

Comment: El problema con la propiedad `break-inside` es que no es soportado (o es incompleto) en la mayoría de navegadores https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Equiso añadí una alternativa que no usa `break-inside` y que funciona de manera similar

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro es exactamente lo que necesito! gracias!!, lo probaré.

Answer (score 1):

Si no te importa mantener el orden de la lista, puedes usar flexbox.

```
ul#rtl_func {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
ul#rtl_func > li {
    display: block;
    min-width: 45%; /* para un pequeño gap entre columnas */
}
```

### DEMO

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  background: #fff;
}
ul#rtl_func {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
ul#rtl_func > li {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'segoe ui', sans-serif;
  margin: 10px 0;
  min-width: 45%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: box-shadow .25s ease;
}
ul#rtl_func > li:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  cursor: default;
}
ul#rtl_func > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}
ul#rtl_func > li > ul > li:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="rtl_func">
<li class="list_root" id="f_0">Tipos de Datos
    <ul id="c_0">
        <li class="list_child">Enteros, Ordinales</li>
        <li class="list_child">Puntos Flotantes</li>
        <li class="list_child">Cadenas, Char</li>
        <li class="list_child">Punteros</li>
        <li class="list_child">Otros</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="list_root" id="f_1">Cadenas y Char
    <ul id="c_1">
        <li class="list_child">Operaciones</li>
        <li class="list_child">Convertir desde</li>
        <li class="list_child">Convertir hacia</li>
        <li class="list_child">Presentación</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="list_root" id="f_0">Tipos de Datos
    <ul id="c_0">
        <li class="list_child">Enteros, Ordinales</li>
        <li class="list_child">Puntos Flotantes</li>
        <li class="list_child">Cadenas, Char</li>
        <li class="list_child">Punteros</li>
        <li class="list_child">Otros</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="list_root" id="f_1">Cadenas y Char
    <ul id="c_1">
        <li class="list_child">Operaciones</li>
        <li class="list_child">Convertir desde</li>
        <li class="list_child">Convertir hacia</li>
        <li class="list_child">Presentación</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="list_root" id="f_2">Estructura del Programa
    <ul id="c_2">
        <li class="list_child">Control del Programa</li>
        <li class="list_child">Datos del Programa</li>
        <li class="list_child">Ciclos</li>
        <li class="list_child">Lógica</li>
        <li class="list_child">Orientado a Objetos</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo que quiero, claro, sin los efectos que propones, voy a jugar con ella, ya le aviso, gracias @MitsuGM

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar el selector `>` para indicar que solo necesitas cambiar los *hijos directos* de un elemento, con hijos directos quiero decir todos elementos dentro de un *root* y que estén lo más cerca a este.

Ejemplo:

```
root-element > direct-child {}

<root-element>
  <direct-child>
    <not-direct-child></not-direct-child>
  </direct-child>
</root-element>

# debe afectar a los hijos directos
element > child {}

# debe afectar a todos sus hijos
element child {}
```

Entonces, uno de tus estilos quedaría así:

```
/* solo afectara al li que es hijo directo de #rtl_func */
#rtl_func > li {
  list-style:none;
  overflow: hidden;
```

**Actualización**
De los comentarios, según @Enecumene el problema se encuentra en el `display: inline`. El estilo correcto sería:

```
#rtl_func > li { display:inline }
```

Esto solo afectaría a los list en:

```
<ul id="rtl_func">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Gracias @learnecys, lo probé y sigue la lista sin dividirse a una segunda columna.

Comment: @Enecumene acabo de actualizar las respuestas, me avisas cualquier duda :)

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo estimado, he actualizado mi jsFiddle con tus recomendaciones y aún sigue sin dividirse en dos columnas, revisalo y verás los resultados.

Comment: @Enecumene podrías agregar una imagen de como deberia aparecer, creo que sería de mucha utilidad. Por cierto, el `display: inline` lo que hace es convertir un elemento en bloque a un elemento en linea, no necesariamente lo transforma a columnas, para conseguir ese resultado, se requiere el manejo de varios estilos.Ya lo reviso :)